# change label of sign in with google button

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-signin

I made a "sign in with google" button, but I just want to change its text to "**sign up** with google " nothing else but I want to change the label, any help, please!
Here is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
     <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxx 
.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
 <body>
   <div id="my-signin2"></div>
     <script>
       function onSuccess(googleUser) {

      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
auth2.signOut();
}//end of googleSignIn
 function onFailure(error) {
   console.log(error);
  }

   //custom google button

function renderButton() {
  gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
    'scope': 'profile email',
    'width': 245,
    'height': 40,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'dark',
    'onsuccess': onSuccess,
    'onfailure': onFailure
        });
  }
   </script>

   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js? 
                onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
     </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: please share your complete html .

Comment: Done @AmitVerma , If you want to use my code, just replace the content from xxxxx with your client id, it works perfectly

Comment: Does this help [link]https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Comment: No, unfortunately @AHaworth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be straightforward to render the new [Sign In With Google button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button) in HTML using the
[data-text](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-text) attribute. Setting `data-text="signup_with"` will render a button called "Sign up with Google" as you asked.

Like the older library shown in your code snippet, the new button supports either a JavaScript callback handler or a back-end server redirect which shares the ID token credential after user sign-in.

Comment: Thanks Mr.bdid , but where should I add this setting in my code, can you tell me ,please !

Comment: You'll just need to add the `g_id_signin` element to your web page, in your example code above it could just replace `signin2`  An HTML code snippet to add the button to a page is available [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button)

Comment: so you couldnt do it with font-awesome or with bootstrap icons?